# how can I write to the byte buffer half way in java?

Tags: java, video, bufferedreader, bytebuffer

Suppose each time the buffer of the input-steam read 1000 bytes.  There are some start signs and the video name at the beginning of the buffer, before the actual video content, like 100 byte. I don't want to write them into the result buffer. So the first time write 101-999 to the buffer. And the second time I hope to write 1000-1999. Currently, it write 0-999 again, and the result video has an 900 extra bytes before the actually video contents.

Is there anyway to write the buffer skipping the first buffer length? thanks!

Comment: You should post some (short, related to the question) code

Comment: In fact, go ahead and add an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to write byte buffer from some offset in Java servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588359/how-to-write-byte-buffer-from-some-offset-in-java-servlet)

Comment: thanks so much for the useful advice! I'm new here, used to find some solutions here, but not quite know how to ask a good question so far.. sorry for being the unprofessional way.. I'm learning to ask a question. And I figured out where was wrong with the program myself, it's the logical problem. Thanks again for the help, and all your sincere advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sophia, you really do need to include example code so people can help, but I see from your tags you are likely asking about NIO's ByteBuffer.

What you want to do is skip the content you don't want by way of the [ByteBuffer.position(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28int%29) method - there is no magic in the ByteBuffer impl, it is a backing data store (either a byte[] or direct memory reference to OS) and a series of int pointers that refer to conceptual positions in the buffer (start, end, limit, etc.) -- you just want to make sure you "skip" the bytes you don't want, which can be done by moving the position beyond it so the next operation to write out the entire buffer will start from position and go to limit.

Comment: Thanks Riyad! You are right, there is no tricky part with the buffer operation, just some logical issues which I've already solved. Thanks again for your advice!

Answer (score 5):

I use this code for skipping bytes from a ByteBuffer:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Utility {
  public static void skip(ByteBuffer bb, int skip) {
    bb.position( bb.position() + skip);
  }
}
```